# Allow user to manually set crop area of default/custom image sizes on upload

Tags: post-thumbnails, plugin-recommendation, images

I'm looking for a plugin that allows the user to define where the image will be cropped for a given thumbnail size.

For example, the user uploads an image, a screen comes up with the image and a selection box, and asks her to move/resize the image within the selection for size 'medium'.

I've found two plugins that allow the user to do this after the thumbnail has been uploaded: [Post Thumbnail Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/) and [Crop-Thumnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/crop-thumbnails/).

Either of these might work, but does anyone know of a built-in solution or a plugin that will ask for this on upload?

There seems to be a built-in solution in the customizer when for example when choosing the logo or header image in twentyseventeen - it opens the upload dialogue and says "Upload and crop" on the button, leading to moving preset crop area in the next step. Any way how to use this in featured images?

Thanks!

Comment: For built in images sizes or for custom ones?

Comment: Both. The defaults and any added with  `add_image_size()`. I guessed I assumed that a plugin would do both with the way the hooks are set up.

Comment: There is built in cropping for default sizes. AFAIK it's hard to implement it for additional sizes - there were no hooks to do it (but I've checked it few versions back...)

Comment: I'm aware that there is default cropping. But sometimes it doesn't crop in the place that the user would like. That's why I'm looking for a solution so that the user can configure what area it crops on an image/thumbnail basis.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Post Thumbnail Editor on many sites, its really very good.

Just remember when it opens, that it opened in a new tab, once you're done cropping, close the tab to get back to where yo were

http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/